# Specified cast is not valid. ASP Radiobutton

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, boolean, .net

I am getting the following error:

```
Specified cast is not valid.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtVerified" runat="server" Visible='<%#!(bool)Eval("ReadOnly") %>' >
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Accept</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Reject</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Value `ReadOnly` is being retrieved successfully from the database and it is `bool` (saved as bit in sql server. What exactly could the problem be?

Exception is also being thrown here when trying to bind the data (Note: `bool test`is just a test to check if variable `ReadOnly` being retrieved properly from the database.

```
DataTable dt = new LeaveLogic().GetManagerUnverifiedLeaveRequests(Convert.ToInt32(Context.User.Identity.Name));
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    bool test = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[0]["ReadOnly"]);
                    RptLeaveRequests.DataSource = dt;
                    RptLeaveRequests.DataBind();
                }
```

More detaield error:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=App_Web_kdnthep4
  StackTrace:
       at ASP.webpages_verifyleaverequests_aspx.__DataBinding__control43(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Samsung\Desktop\Development\Ticketing system\1.PresentationLayer\WebPages\VerifyLeaveRequests.aspx:line 35
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect()
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex, ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.DataBind()
       at _1.PresentationLayer.WebPages.VerifyLeaveRequests.BindData() in C:\Users\Samsung\Desktop\Development\Ticketing system\1.PresentationLayer\WebPages\VerifyLeaveRequests.aspx.cs:line 58
       at _1.PresentationLayer.WebPages.VerifyLeaveRequests.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Samsung\Desktop\Development\Ticketing system\1.PresentationLayer\WebPages\VerifyLeaveRequests.aspx.cs:line 24
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Is any HTML actually being generated?  Does the stack trace point to the radio button list declaration?  Have you tried `.ToString()` at the end of the `Eval` call to place either `True` or `False` into the attribute value?

Comment: I want to set the opposite thus the '!' and 'bool' conversion

Comment: With only the small code snippet and partial error message, it is difficult to determine what is happening.  Can you expand on your code here to shed some light on the situation?  Can you also explain your choice to use `Eval` instead of a more direct reference to the underlying property?

Comment: Please check updated. I want the radio button to be visible if the `ReadOnly` is false and not visible when `ReadOnly` is true from the database.

Comment: Just tested and this kind of scenario should work, are you sure that none of the rows returned have for example null value in the Readonly-field? Also are you sure it's that radiobuttonlist that is the one that causes the exception?

Comment: You're doing a `Convert` to test the value, but then you're doing a type cast when you use the value.  I believe the `Convert` is more "forgiving" when it comes to null values.  Try using the `Convert` with the `Eval` statement and see what you get.

Comment: If you still have troubles, please include more of the aspx code around the radio button list.

Comment: @Tls I just found out that the `ReadOnly` in the database was save as `int` instead of `bit` and therefore values were being retrieved successfully as true/false but the casting was wrong. thanks for your help